# Reading multiple text files from directory line by line JAVA

Tags: java, file, text, directory

Could someone give me an example of how you could read in a directory of text files and read each text file line by line using Java?

So far I have:

```
    String files;
    File folder = new File(file_path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles(); 

       for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

       if (listOfFiles[i].isFile())  {

                // do something here??
            }
      }
```

Comment: You should start by going through [this I/O tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/). I feel like I've linked it 10 times tonight.

Comment: `"Could someone give me an example of ... " ` -- this is not a code factory. What specific question do you have?

Answer (score 6):

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;


public class MyProg {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String target_dir = "./test_dir";
        File dir = new File(target_dir);
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        for (File f : files) {
            if(f.isFile()) {
                BufferedReader inputStream = null;

                try {
                    inputStream = new BufferedReader(
                                    new FileReader(f));
                    String line;

                    while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                }
                finally {
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Java javadocs, look up FileReader, then BufferedReader -- the first reads a file, the second takes a reader as a constructor parameter and has a readline() method.

I agree this is a poor question, but file I/O is difficult to discern without some guidance, and the tutorials often spend too much time with things that you don't need for this purpose.  You *should* still go through the tutorial, but this will get you started for this purpose.

Comment: Please post this as a comment, not as an answer.